# Max and min not working on input

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs app, I have input field, where i need to type number. I set max and min value like this

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="{{totaImpressionsSum}}"/>
```

On `$scope.totaImpressionsSum` i get value from controller, in this case this value is 5000.

When I inspect in console this, max value is properly set. 
[image]

I also try with ng-max and ng-min... 
But anything of this not working, I still can type number smaller than 0 and greater than 5000.

What I doing wrong? 
In another place this working correct... but here not...

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLLCfo4mHwfRFNTHb2jM?p=preview)

Comment: Can you reproduce this situation at fiddler?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov i update my question

Comment: if i remember correctly, this is browser issue. chrome behaves differently than firefox for example...

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. If you want to prevent user from entering values beyond the specified range, you need to write your own logic to cap the min/max values.

Comment: also this is not how browsers are implementing it. min/max attributes are taken into account when dealing with validation, but you as a user are allowed to put there invalid input (in terms of min/max constraints).

Comment: @MartinAdámek i try validation max and min in firefox, chrome and opera.... and same problem...

Comment: @31piy do you have any suggestion? Also i try this, https://codepen.io/Jaydo/pen/yOMZJd but if i enter greater number result is NaN

Answer (score 6):

This is not how `min/max` attributes work - they are taken into account when dealing with validity, but they do not restrict user from what they want to type.

Imagine you would put there `min="10"` and then you would like to type in number `10`. But you can not, as you would first need to type number `1` followed by `0`, but number `1` is not valid input itself.

Take a look at MDN example how they use `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-class:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing `ng-model`, I updated your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H2PQDrzPHP6nPuYhkx49?p=preview)

With min/max you will be able to use the angularsjs form validators. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can disable a button depending on form validation.

Here is a more complete example:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="number" ng-model="test" min="0" max="{{totaImpressionsSum}}"/>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I named the form. Then the directive `ng-disalbed` allows me to disable the submit button if the form is invalid.

Comment: thnx, i miss only in plunker...in my app i use ng-model, but still not working

Comment: It should have been a comment.

Comment: I was writting a more complete answer, I also updated the plunkr